# Return distinct groups

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given this query:

```
match (store)-->(food1)-[:LIKE*]-(food2)<--(store)
return food1 + collect(distinct food2) as group
```

I get results like this:

```
group
[orange, apple, banana],
[orange, banana, apple],
[apple, orange, banana],
[apple, banana, orange],
[banana, orange, apple],
[banana, apple, orange],
[melon, watermelon],
[watermelon, melon]
```

I expected only 2 groups instead of 8. How can I get distinct groups?

Answer (score 2):

List equality with Cypher includes order, so the easiest way would be to sort the lists, preferably with `apoc.coll.sortNodes()` from APOC Procedures, which allows sorting within collections, which will then allow DISTINCT to provide correct results.

That said, there are some issues with that query to fix up.

First, you should be using labels, otherwise this turns into an AllNodesScan. :Store and :Food labels should probably be used. Also relationships usually matter, so use relationship types in your query if possible.

You can also reduce the number of variables involved by using a variable-length relationship with a lower bound of 0.

Also, to prevent lots of duplicates, since you don't seem to care about stores in the query results, it would probably work best to only have one store in the MATCH, order and collect the foods, then get the lists where the count of the lists is > 1 (meaning more than one store has a relationship to those same foods).

```
MATCH (s:Store)-[:CARRIES]->(:Food)-[:LIKE*0..]-(food:Food)
WITH s, food
ORDER BY id(food) DESC
WITH s, collect(food) as foods
WITH foods, count(foods) as count
WHERE count > 1
RETURN foods
```